# How to get all not unique elements

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried this:

```
SELECT g.gname 
FROM GLAS g 
WHERE NOT UNIQUE (SELECT g.gid FROM COCKTAIL c WHERE g.gid = c.gid);
```

I'm using an oracle database and the oracle sql developer who tells me

> ORA-00936 missing expression.

Got no idea what could be missing.
My aim is to get all glasses that are used for 2 or more cocktails. It is a tutorial exercise but couldn't solve it.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group by` with `having`.

```
SELECT g.gname 
FROM GLAS g 
join COCKTAIL c on g.gid = c.gid
group by g.gname
having count(*) >= 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but i'm still interested in the reason for the error and what exactly i'm doing wrong.

Comment: NOT UNIQUE is not a [valid condition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions.htm#g1077361) in an Oracle query.